# Any way to access cookies in SilkTest?

Tags: testing, cookies, automation

We're testing a web application using SilkTest 2008R2, and need to check the value of the cookies periodically.

We currently use javascript via the ExecLine function:

```
BrowserPage.ExecLine ("alert(document.cookie.split(';').join('/n'))", TRUE)
```

and then just read the text off the resulting popup.

This is somewhat errorprone.

Is there any other way to get at the cookies in SilkTest?  would be a way to do it using only native `SilkTest` functionality.